# Disable or Hide System menu options

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

How to disable the window context menu options like "Restore" , "Move", "Minimize" , "Maximize" and "Close" or else prevent the right click?

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer because I don't have any code, but unless WPF does something special, you should be able to do that with pinvoke and some Win32 API functions: ["The menu items in a window menu can be modified by using the GetSystemMenu, AppendMenu, InsertMenu, ModifyMenu, InsertMenuItem, and SetMenuItemInfo functions. Applications that modify the window menu must process WM_SYSCOMMAND messages."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-2) (scroll down a few lines).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks for the reply , i am using maha app metro window. i found an solution in that as ShowsystemMenuOnRightClick="true", it hides the context menu.

Comment: Ohh, you just want to get rid of the whole thing, not disable specific items. Much easier!

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yup!! Anyway Thanks buddy

Comment: @EdPlunkett Do u have example for your answer , if yes means can you please mention the link?

Comment: As I said, I don't have any code. The pinvoke declarations for the API functions are probably [all on pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=GetSystemMenu&namespace=[All]). Dealing with menus via Win32 API is going to be a bit tedious, compared to what you're used to.

Comment: I think, it isn't possible, because very big companys still have this thing in their programms.